# Ayuda para cerrar menu acordeón

Tags: jquery, menú

Tengo un menú acordeón, pero no sé como cerrarlo, siempre queda abierto, este es el código:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <ul id="nav">
                    <li style="background:url(http://lineadetiempoups.ec/img/bgmenudeplegable.png) center top no-repeat; padding:10px;"><a href="lineatiempo.html">Linea de Tiempo</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#"><img src="http://lineadetiempoups.ec/img/linea_fecha.png" width="76" height="34" alt=""/></a>
            <ul style="margin-top:12px;">
             <!-- <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>-->
                <li style="background:none;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;"><a href="galerias.html">Imágenes</a></li>                   
                    <li style="background:none;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;"><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                    <li style="background:none;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;"><a href="libro.html">Libro</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
         
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un problema al hacer la animación le estas poniendo `.slideToggle()` el cual hace un efecto de abrir o cerrar dependiendo del caso que aplique.
Y como anteriormente tienes un `slideUp()` el `slideToggle` lo que hará es abrirlo nuevamente, entonces mi solución es que lo dejes en `slideUp()` y pongas un else y ahi pongas el `slideToggle()` o en otro caso el `slideDown()`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
      $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideUp();
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }else{
      $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <ul id="nav">
                    <li style="background:url(http://lineadetiempoups.ec/img/bgmenudeplegable.png) center top no-repeat; padding:10px;"><a href="lineatiempo.html">Linea de Tiempo</a></li>
          <li ><a href="#"><img src="http://lineadetiempoups.ec/img/linea_fecha.png" width="76" height="34" alt=""/></a>
            <ul style="margin-top:12px;">
             <!-- <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>-->
                <li style="background:none;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;"><a href="galerias.html">Imágenes</a></li>                   
                    <li style="background:none;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;"><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                    <li style="background:none;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;"><a href="libro.html">Libro</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
         
        </ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, se ha solucionado todo..